# Convert each json item to json object in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with below 4 columns

```
ID  Name     Date      MetaData
1    abc     5/4/2021   "{'IsAdult': 1,'IsMale': 1,'IsFemale': 0,'IsManager': 0}"
2    xyz     5/4/2021   "{'IsAdult': 1,'IsMale': 1,'IsFemale': 0,'IsManager': 0}"
```

I want to convert the last columns each item to json so the last column metedata looks like this, where all values are static only updatecount is actual column value and dates are current date.

I am a beginner in python, Any help on how to achieve this

```json
{
    "IsAdult": {
        "USERCREATOR": -36969,
        "USERMODIFIER": -36969,
        "CREATIONDATE": "2021-05-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "LASTMODIF": "2021-05-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "ISACTIVE": 1,
        "COMMENTS": "",
        "GROUPNAME": "",
        "UPDATECOUNT": 1,
        "ISCOMMENTPUBLISHED": 0
    },
    "IsMale": {
        "USERCREATOR": -36969,
        "USERMODIFIER": -36969,
        "CREATIONDATE": "2021-05-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "LASTMODIF": "2021-05-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "ISACTIVE": 1,
        "COMMENTS": "",
        "GROUPNAME": "",
        "UPDATECOUNT": 1,
        "ISCOMMENTPUBLISHED": 0
    },
    "IsFemale": {
        "USERCREATOR": -36969,
        "USERMODIFIER": -36969,
        "CREATIONDATE": "2021-05-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "LASTMODIF": "2021-05-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "ISACTIVE": 1,
        "COMMENTS": "",
        "GROUPNAME": "",
        "UPDATECOUNT": 0,
        "ISCOMMENTPUBLISHED": 0
    },
    "IsManager": {
        "USERCREATOR": -36969,
        "USERMODIFIER": -36969,
        "CREATIONDATE": "2021-05-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "LASTMODIF": "2021-05-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "ISACTIVE": 1,
        "COMMENTS": "",
        "GROUPNAME": "",
        "UPDATECOUNT": 0,
        "ISCOMMENTPUBLISHED": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the source of the last column? That last column *is not valid JSON*. It looks like someone just did `str(some_dict)`

Comment: I am getting it from an API

Answer (score 0):

One way you can alter this metadata is using
`.apply` or `.map` function for pd DataFrames.

You can define a function that takes in your original metadata as input and perhaps an id.
Pseudocode:

```
def afunc(metadata, id):

  # Alter metadata
  # Change dates if provide a single metadata
  UPDATECOUNT = id % 2 or something that changes update count

  return new_meta_data
```

Then as per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html documentation or some other doc on .map. You can actually apply that function on every single row of your dataset.

Sarthak Jain